# Converting foreach into single pass Linq Group By

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of items that may have one or more properties.

I want to use a Linq statement (query syntax) to filter and group that list in a single pass such that it checks for a mandatory property first, and then looks for an optional property.

I can't figure out how to do this without first filtering the list and then going over it again to look for the optional property.

Here's how I could do it in a foreach statement. (Not efficient, just illustrating what I need.)

```
var usefulBoxes = new Dictionary<Box, int>;

foreach (box in cart)
{
  bool boxNeeded = false;
  int someCounter = 0;

  foreach (prop in box.Properties)
  {
    if (prop == neededProp)
      boxNeeded = true;
    else if (boxNeeded && prop == optionalProp)
      someCounter += 1;
  }

  if (boxNeeded)
    usefulBoxes.Add(box, someCounter)
}
```

Comment: What is `boxProperties`?

Comment: It's a collection different property objects derived from the same class.

Comment: You mean `PropertyInfo` instances?

Comment: No, it's just a custom collection for the example. Is it confusing? I can change it.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Your inner loop does not depends on outer loop. It just doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Quite right! Properties are part of the box, I've made the change.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var usefulBoxes= box.where(b=>b.boxProperties.prop==neededProp).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this code does, and how it solves the OP's problem?

Comment: I think what he need is usefulBoxes based on the condition (prop == neededProp), so what i did here is filtered the box on the same condition. also note if (boxNeeded && prop == optionalProp) he dont want  boxNeeded to be set true, infact he dont like to add the same to  usefulBoxes

Answer (score 0):

this your demo linq:

```
var usefulBoxes = new Dictionary<List<int>, int>();
        foreach (var boxNeeded in from box in cart let boxNeeded = false let someCounter = 0 from prop in box.Properties.Where(prop => prop == neededProp) select boxNeeded)
        {
            if (prop == neededProp)
                boxNeeded = true;
            else if (boxNeeded && prop == optionalProp)
                someCounter += 1;
            if (boxNeeded)
                usefulBoxes.Add(box, someCounter);
        }
```